# Como fazer um linha horizontal em relevo?

Tags: html, css

Muitos sites utilizam uma espécie de `<hr>` em relevo, ex:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já faz algum tempo que tenho tentado fazer na mão sem sucesso. Também não achei nada sobre isso na internet

```
<div>
  &nbsp;<hr>&nbsp;
</div>

div{
  width:300px;
  background-color:#eee;
  padding:10px;
}
hr{
  height:2px;
  border:1px inset #fff;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tem muitas maneiras diferentes. O `hr` nem sempre reage como esperado, caso você não tenha problemas em usar outro elemento, um jeito simples é esse:

```css
.hr {
  border-top:1px solid #ccc;
  border-bottom:1px solid #fff;
}
body {background:#eee}
```

```html
1
<div class="hr"></div>
2
```

Se for dar suporte apenas a navegadores mais novos, pode usar `rgba(0,0,0,.2)` e `rgba(255,255,255,.2)` para funcionar em qualquer fundo (preto e branco com transparência `.2`)

A mesma técnica pode ser aplicada no `hr`, mas tem que tomar cuidado com o jeito que os elementos são estilizados em navegadores diferentes. Em alguns casos o `hr` é implementado com bordas, em outros como borda + conteudo.

O CSS também tem o `inset` para o mesmo efeito, mas aí você tem menos controle sobre a parte clara e escura.

Veja o inset aplicado a um `hr`:

```css
hr {
  height:0;
  width:100%;
  border:1px inset #eee;
}

body {background:#eee}
```

```html
1
<hr>
2
```